# Why is there a pressure drop across a Kaplan turbine?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, thermodynamics

The [Kaplan turbine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kaplan_turbine) is an inward flow reaction turbine, which means that the working fluid changes its static pressure as it moves through the turbine and gives up energy. But how does this pressure drop happen? Why does the static pressure of water drop when it flows across a Kaplan turbine?

Comment: [**Probably useful**](http://community.dur.ac.uk/g.l.ingram/download/kaplandesign.pdf)

Comment: See pp. 11-12 of [this dissertation](http://pure.ltu.se/portal/files/36434087/Berhanu_Mulu_Geberkiden.pdf)